# MFC: How to catch set focus of each control of dialog in one function

Tags: c++, mfc, setfocus

I have "n" dialogs which have the same base dialog. Each dialog has its own controls

- edit boxes
- combo boxes
- list controls
- etc.

In base dialog, how do I set focus messages of each control and,for example, give a Message box with

```
text("Hello I got focus, my ID is %d")?
```

Comment: You'd probably want to use a message hook to catch the WM_SETFOCUS  message.

Comment: Yah something like this, but I have tried to catch  WM_SETFOCUS , in PreTranslateMessage, OnChildNotify and in OnNotify and nothing helps, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2144805/1850797), you can hook the `WM_SETFOCUS` message.

You can get the Control ID by using [`GetDlgCtrlID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645478(v=vs.90).aspx) with the `hwnd` returned by the hook.

But beware of popping up a `MessageBox`, that will change the focus and trigger your hook proc, making it go into a loop!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using the classical subclassing method. The problem is that `WM_SETFOCUS` is not pumped through the message Loop, so `PreTranslateMessage` will not help.

Thee are some nice classes that help to do additional subclassing without disturbing the MFC stuff.
Paul Di Lascia wrote `CSubclassWnd`. PJ Naughter wrote `CHookWnd`. And with the ATL has `CWindowsImpl`.

All this classes allow easy additional subclassing even if a window is already subclassed by the MFC.

You can use "standard subclassing" `GetWindowLong`/`SetWindowLong` too.

Answer (score 0):

As Jerry already said make a hook, get parent window handler via  [GetParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x2wyab0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [SendMessage(hParentWND, WM_MESSAGE, lParam, wParam)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). 
Of course, you should handle WM_MESSAGE in your parent window. 
Btw, framework calls [OnSetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx1ea34a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function when window gained focus.