# How to determine when a child dialog, or one of its children, gains and loses focus

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog

Is there a standard way to determine when a child dialog (i.e., one with `WS_CHILD` / `DS_CONTROL`), or one of its own children, gains and loses focus?

It seems like when a dialog is top-level, then `WM_ACTIVATE` would be the appropriate event, both for gaining and losing.

But if I understand correctly, that's not an option for dialogs that are themselves children.  And in using Spy++, there doesn't appear to be a standard message that coincides with the child dialog gaining and losing focus.  Granted, `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` appears to be sent to the child dialog, at least when activation is done by mouse, but that seems mouse-dependent, and it also doesn't occur when focus is lost.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990361/mfc-how-to-catch-set-focus-of-each-control-of-dialog-in-one-function) help?

Comment: Hm, I'd prefer to avoid setting hooks.  If you have to go through that much trouble, I guess I'll just capture all of the notify and command focus messages sent from the dialog's controls.

Comment: Hooks are pretty easy to use. The system is designed around them, they're not a kludge or anything.

Comment: Why would that be an event worth getting notified about? What are you planning to be doing in response to that event?

Comment: @IInspectable Well I'm implementing a File Explorer toolband extension and would like to receive accelerator messages through `IInputObject`.  In order for this to happen, I believe you need to call the site object's `IInputObjectSite::OnFocusChangeIS` method when your window gains or loses focus -- although upon further experimentation, I think it may not be strictly necessary to call it when losing focus.  In any event, I use a child dialog in my extension, so I wanted to figure out when it gains and loses focus in order to properly call `OnFocusChangeIS`.